# DataContext as Source for Converter Binding Within Resources

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, controltemplate, ivalueconverter

```
 <Canvas.DataContext>
  <ViewModels:VMSomeControl Model="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
 </Canvas.DataContext>

 <!-- DataContext is not passed into these Instances.
      they also have no knowledge of their TemplatedParent. -->
 <Canvas.Resources>

  <!--  is there a way to use a binding that points to the datacontext within the resources ? -->
  <Converters:SomeConverter x:Key="someConverter" 
                            SomeProperty="{Binding Path=Model.SomeProperty}" />

  <!--  is there a way to point Directly to the TemplatedParent  ? -->
  <Converters:SomeConverter x:Key="someConverter" 
                            SomeProperty="{TemplateBinding SomeProperty}" />

 </Canvas.Resources>


 <SomeFrameworkElement SomeProperty="{Binding Path=Model.SomeOtherProperty, Converter={StaticResource someConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />

 <SomeFrameworkElement SomeProperty="{Binding Path=Model.SomeOtherProperty, Converter={StaticResource someConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />

</Canvas>
```

is it possible to use bindings that use either the dataContext or the TemplatedParent
Within a ControlTemplate's Root Visuals resourecs ?

Comment: for some reason stackoverflow truncated my style and control template.
this Canvas is at the root of the control template.

Answer (score 11):

Previous answer is reeeeally really close. but the binding inside the multibinding should be :

```
<SomeFrameworkElement>
    <SomeFrameworkElement.SomeProperty>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someConverter}" >
            <Binding />
        </MultiBinding>        
    </SomeFrameworkElement.SomeProperty>
</SomeFrameworkElement>
```

that worked for me

Comment: In my case throws an exception "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.". I'm binding Text property of TextBox.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>If you want your value converter to be able to access the datacontext you may want to use ConverterParameter instead:</strike>

```
<SomeFrameworkElement SomeProperty="{Binding Path=Model.SomeOtherProperty, Converter={StaticResource someConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding DataContext}}" />
```

The datacontext will then be passed on to your value converter as a parameter to your implementation of [IValueConverter.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert(v=VS.100).aspx).

---

You may be able to pass bindable parameters to your valueconverter if you implement [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) and bind the parameters using the [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) class in XAML:

```
<SomeFrameworkElement>
    <SomeFrameworkElement.SomeProperty>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someConverter}" >
            <Binding Path="DataContext"/>
        </MultiBinding>        
    </SomeFrameworkElement.SomeProperty>
</SomeFrameworkElement>
```

The binding elements of the `<MultiBinding>` element are passed to the `Convert` method of `IMultiValueConverter` as the `values` parameter.  `Convert` has the following signature:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
```

Comment: unfortunately you cannot use a binding on "ConverterParameter"
that would be REALLY handy though.

Comment: You are of course absolutely right.  But I think you may be able to use mulitbinding for this.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i have not yet had a chance to test this as i have been working on some other projects. but i will be sure to give you credit if it solves my issue.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for pointing me in the direction of using the IMultiValueConverter interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeProperty="{Binding . ,Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, ConverterParameter=someParam}"
```

The dot is telling that you binding to datacontext

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple and efficient way (that works for my app):

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="ColumnHeader">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverterKey}" ConverterParameter="DataContext"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Now you can use (value) in the `Convertor` method as your `DataContext`.

Comment: This gives one the text `DataContext` in the converter.